# How do I pass an Array of ids from Rails 3 controller to a Javascript Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

Im trying to grab the ids of the images using rails, pass those ids to javascript and then flip through them using a javascript Image Viewer.
This is what I have in my rails controller

```
@rails_array = Images.all
```

this is in my view file

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
 var myIds=new Array(<% @rails_array %>);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to pass any object to javascript is through JSON:

```
var myId= <%= @rails_array.to_json %> ;
```

*Note*: You'll need to append `.html_safe` for strings & hashes (or arrays containing them), but it isn't needed for arrays of integers.

Answer (score 3):

You can collect Ids from controller like this:

```
@rails_array = Images.all.map &:id
```

In the View:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
   var myIds= <%= @rails_array %>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi have you tried [split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method of javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var myId=<% @rails_array %>.split(/,/);
 </script>
```